# ¿Cómo ignoro algunas filas cuando uso la función sort?

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento

Tengo un arreglo de objetos y quiero ordenarlo según una propiedad, pero quisiera que la función sort ignore algunas filas.

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente arreglo y quisiera ignorar el índice 1:

```
var datos = [
                {"asd1":"prueba11", "asd2":"prueba12", "asd3":"prueba13", "asd4":"prueba14", "asd5":"prueba15"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba21", "asd2":"prueba22", "asd3":"prueba23", "asd4":"prueba24", "asd5":"prueba25"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba11", "asd2":"prueba42", "asd3":"prueba43", "asd4":"prueba44", "asd5":"prueba45"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba31", "asd2":"prueba32", "asd3":"prueba33", "asd4":"prueba34", "asd5":"prueba35"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba41", "asd2":"prueba42", "asd3":"prueba43", "asd4":"prueba44", "asd5":"prueba45"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba51", "asd2":"prueba52", "asd3":"prueba53", "asd4":"prueba54", "asd5":"prueba55"}
            ];
```

Y tengo la siguiente función para ordenar:

```
var x = "asd2";
datos.sort(function(a,b) {return (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b))?((a[x] > b[x]) ? 1 : ((b[x] > a[x]) ? -1 : 0)):(a - b);} );
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que ignore (y mantenga en el mismo lugar) al índice 1?

Comment: ignorar, porque después, dicho arreglo, se muestra en una tabla y quiero que el usuario pueda mantener un dato en su lugar si así lo desea.

Comment: Primero : Tu función arroja error en **x**,  Segundo cual es el criterio para ignorar ???

Comment: Cierto lo de x, saqué el código del código directamente y hace referencia a la propiedad sobre la cuál ordenar. El criterio para ignorar debería ser el índice del arreglo.

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres hacer: ¿recombinar los objetos?

Comment: @PabloLozano quiero ordenar el arreglo pero que me mantenga la posición de una fila, es decir que si tengo la siguiente lista: "a, c, e, b, d" y quiero mantener el elemento "c" en el índice 1, el resultado del ordenamiento debería ser "a, c, b, d, e"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo no se si es la funcionalidad que buscas , lo que hice fue pasar el array **Datos** a un nuevo **array** y a ese le realizas el **sort**, investigue y no encontré como ignorar directamente con alguna propiedad o función para el Sort, aparte cambie tu función **sort**, la comparación en el **IF** puedes cambiar 1 por una variable o lo que quieras

```js
var datos = [
                {"asd1":"prueba11",  "asd3":"prueba13",   "asd2":"prueba12","asd4":"prueba14", "asd5":"prueba15"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba21", "asd2":"prueba22","asd5":"prueba25" ,"asd3":"prueba23", "asd4":"prueba24"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba11", "asd2":"prueba42", "asd3":"prueba43", "asd4":"prueba44", "asd5":"prueba45"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba31", "asd2":"prueba32", "asd3":"prueba33", "asd4":"prueba34", "asd5":"prueba35"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba41", "asd2":"prueba42", "asd3":"prueba43", "asd4":"prueba44", "asd5":"prueba45"}, 
                {"asd1":"prueba51", "asd2":"prueba52", "asd3":"prueba53", "asd4":"prueba54", "asd5":"prueba55"}
            ];
const datos2 = [];
console.log(datos);
console.log("---------------------------------");

datos.forEach(function(x, i){
console.log(i)
  if(i != 1){
    datos2.push(x);
  }
});

datos2.sort(function (a, b) {
    //console.log("variables: " + a.asd1 +" - "+ b.asd1)
      if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    
console.log("----------------Array sin el indice 1-----------------");

console.log(datos2);
```

Comment: interesante, creas una variable aparte, sin el índice bloqueado, ordenas la variable nueva, y luego con la función splice podría insertar las filas ignoradas en el ordenamiento, ¿no?

Comment: para comparar string recomiendo `str1.localeCompare(str2);` asi verifica las mayuscula,minuscula y numeros bien, cambiaria todo el if del sort por `return !!a.name ? -1 : a.name.localeCompare(b.name)`